# if (is_archive()) not working wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I know a fair bit about HTML, CSS, jQuery but I haven't dabbled with PHP yet. I was given a code to help me apply a style to the webpage, only if it was a blog page:

```
<?php if(is_archive()){ ?>
<style type="text/css">
     .wrap {
         max-width: 1200px !important;
      }
</style>
<?php } ?>
```

This, inserted into the header file, has worked perfectly since. On my return to work after a short absence I find that this code is still in the same place it has always been but is no longer effective? As the code gives the archive pages a max-width, these now look dreadful without it because the margin: 0 auto doesn't work either.

Take a look for yourself [here](http://7connections.com/blog/). I'm not sure if this code is written correctly because I recently found that hostgator's file browser editor had added code to files I'd edited when I was out of office. Any help is appreciated but please bear in mind that I know nothing about PHP, other than where to copy and paste it.

Comment: not for me, the single post page is 100% width, and the main archive page is floating left, because the margin 0 auto isn't effective without the max width. The whole thing should be centred.

Comment: where you define that? Cant found it on the source code. make sure that you define that **after** the stylesheets. Are you sure that the site is an `Archive`? Otherwise try `is_category()`

Comment: it's the last line in the header.php file after all the other stylesheets

Comment: hmm @Joe the page you link to works fine, but previously this code worked perfect for the single post page and the main blog page?

Comment: @Joe this is the problem, if the main stylesheet is edited there are lots of pages that need to be full width. That's why in the beginning I set max-width to 100% and used PHP to only change the max-width on these pages.

Comment: Ah, ok - then just use this CSS: `body.page-template-page_blog-php .wrap, body.archive .wrap, body.single-post .wrap{ max-width: 1200px !important; }`. This will target the home blog page, the archive page and all your posts. Hope that helps!

Comment: You have a CSS spaghetti on this website, dozens of rules overriding each other. The only way to get it working is what @Joe suggests but since using `!important` is not a good practice you should consider this as a hotfix solution and the longterm solution is to rewrite your CSS.

Comment: I will give this a go tomorrow morning @Joe, the code looks like a goodun. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing your normal wrap class with this:

```
<div class="wrap<?php echo (is_archive()) ? ' full-width' : ''; ?>">
```

Then you can access this via `#container .wrap.full-width {width: 1200px!important;}`